# How to capture result for multiple beanshell assertions in JMeter by using Simple Data Writer?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using multiple beanshell assertions in a single http request and saving assertion results in csv file by using simple data writer. The problem is, in csv file only first assertion result is getting captured. Please help. Attaching the snapshots.

Comment: You didn't  attach the snapshots, show your code

Answer (score 0):

It looks line JMeter stores only 1st assertion failure result in CSV format, consider raising an [enhancement request](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime you can consider ticking `Save as XML` box in the Simple Data Writer:

[image]

this way you will have all the Assertion Failure messages stored in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample t="160" it="0" lt="160" ct="31" ts="1544693846139" s="false" lb="HTTP Request" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="1597" sby="115" ng="1" na="1">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>BeanShell Assertion</name>
    <failure>true</failure>
    <error>false</error>
    <failureMessage>msg1</failureMessage>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>BeanShell Assertion</name>
    <failure>true</failure>
    <error>false</error>
    <failureMessage>msg2</failureMessage>
  </assertionResult>
  <java.net.URL>http://example.com/</java.net.URL>
</httpSample>

</testResults>
```

---

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) language for any form of scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) on next available opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but please tell me what if I want to capture the Success/Failure message in excel by using Groovy as in bean shell we can do by using FailureMessage.